# CSS3 hover animation failed after closed fancybox

Tags: jquery, css, hover, fancybox

In my project, I have animation of CSS transition (like a bubble). Here to be exact, [CSS3 Bubble](http://www.admixweb.com/2010/05/12/creating-a-bubble-coda-style-with-css3/) and combined with fancybox link after hovering the bubble. It works fine for iframe, image elements, **but once i open up the YouTube link, the fancybox works fine but i couldn't hover my trigger element again.**

Has anyone experienced this problem or figured out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I think I got it. By force-setting the jquery of youtube element to "iframe" with the provided url, the video seems to run just like iframe itself! :)